# how to pass function to container component based on the route in angular

Tags: angular

I have an `angular13` app & the component structure looks something like below

```
app
   common
     footer
        button
   pages
     section (container component)
       section-a  (route1)
       section-b  (route2)
       section-c // & so on a-t
```

**Each section has a form with its own model. In the `footer` component, I have a submit button, on the click of which I need to call an API with the respective section's form data**.

I'm not getting clue how can I attach the function scoped to a section to be called on the button click of the parent component.

If I had to call a common function I could have easily used the `@Output aka Event Emitter)` in `section.component.ts` however here in this case, I want/need to bind a section-specific function to the footer button click.

> How can I pass/attach function to be called on the button click based

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service with a Subject which you call in the footer and in the Section component you can subscribe to the subject and do your logic.

From the top of my head:

SectionService

```
submit$ = new Subject<void>();
```

Footer

```
constructor(private sectionService:SectionService){}
submit(){
    this.sectionService.submit$.next();
}
```

Section container component

```
 constructor(private sectionService:SectionService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.sectionService.submit$
        .pipe(
           switchMap(()=>{ //depends on what you need
               // do whatever
           )
         )
        .subscribe()
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. can I ask you to share some pseudo code around it?

Comment: I added some example code.